# Fail to echo out the value from database due to jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The below code works fine, but when i try to save the value to the database, it fail to show the value.

To be more precisely, it could show for less than a second, i can see the value from the database flash before my eyes, then the value remains to be the original one before the save.

I want to be able to retrieve the value from db and update the value as well.
eg if certain row of payment has been paid, the updated amount will be saved to db.

Right now, i can save it to db, but fail to echo out the db value for further update

Here's the php code

```
<td><textarea  class="total_sum_value" rows="" cols="5"  style="border: none" name="total[]"><?php echo $row['total'] ?></textarea> </td>


 <td><textarea  class="arrears" rows="" cols="5"  style="border: none" name="arrears[]"><?php echo $row['arrears'] ?></textarea> </td>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal, .status', function() {
    calculate();
  });

  function calculate() {
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;
    var to_be_paid = 0;

    $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
      var get_textbox_value = $('.txtCal', this).val();
      var get_payment_status = $('.status', this).val();
      
      if (get_textbox_value && get_payment_status) {
        if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
          calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
        }

        if (get_payment_status === 'N') {
          to_be_paid += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
        }
      }
    });
    $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
    $("#arrears").html(to_be_paid);
  }

  calculate();


});
```

```css
    <?php 
include_once('connect-db.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($_POST['patientid'] as $index => $patientid) {
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$index]);
        
  $data23 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total'][$index]);
  $data24 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['arrears'][$index]);
  
  
     
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET patientid ='$data1',hkid ='$data20',treatmentname3='$data5', totalnooftreatment='$data6',
  nthtreatment='$data7',date='$data8',nextdate='$data9',skip='$data10',language='$data11',smsorcall='$data17',
  engmessage='$data14',status='$data15',nurse='$data16',paymentmethod='$data22', price='$data18',paystatus='$data19',remark='$data21'
  ,total='$data23',arrears='$data24'
  WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
        
  
      header("Location: displaypatientall.php");
  }
        }
  
        ?>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th width="100">Name </th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Payment status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>A</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="50" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>B :</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>C:</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="N" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
      <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span><b>Yet to be paid</b></span></td>
      <td><b><span id="arrears"></span></b></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your php script for getting saved values from database and showing it, if page is refreshed.

Comment: Where's the code for saving the data? The ajax call, the script, etc. The Code Snippet you put works well, but doesnt have any of the database code that is what you're asking for...

Comment: What do you mean when you see the value flashing? Where are you seeing this? And why you want to echo your updated value? You don't have this info already?

Comment: I can see the value but only for less than a second.It's fixed now, it's the cache issues

Comment: Hi Tam! You shouldn't add "[closed]" to question titles on Stack Overflow. If you've solved the issue and have an interesting solution, you can add an answer an accept it. If it was a small technical issue, you can also delete the question. Thanks!